# Вывод всех драйверов OC

Tags: powershell, драйвер

Необходимо в powershell прочитать *.inf файлы: "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" и вывести в таблицу: Manufacter, DeviceID, VerDRV.

Есть некие наработки, но выглядит все печально.

```
ls "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\" -Recurse -File -Filter *.inf | %{

$mtch = $_ |Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "^\[(.+)\]$|^([^;].+)=(.+[^;])"
$infObj = New-Object pscustomobject
$mtch.Matches | % {
if ($_.Groups[1].Success) {
    $section = $_.Groups[1].Value
    Add-Member -InputObject $infObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $section -Value (New-Object pscustomobject)
} else {
    Add-Member -InputObject $infObj.$section -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Groups[2].Value -Value $_.Groups[3].Value
}
}



$infObj.Version |  Format-Table
$infObj = $null
$mtch = $null
$section = $null }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подправил скрипт "n01d". В результате, почти идеально, то что я хотел бы увидеть:

```
Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" -Recurse -File -Filter '*.inf' | ForEach-Object {
    $fileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName
    #write-host ">>>>>" + $_.FullName

    $dirverVer = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'DriverVer=') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    #$Provider = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Provider=') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    $Provider = ($fileContent | Select-String '^\s*Provider\s*=.*') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    if ($Provider.Length -eq 0) {
        $Provider = ""
    }
    elseif($Provider.Length -gt 0 -And $Provider -is [system.array]) {
        if ($Provider.Length -gt 1 -And $Provider[0].Trim(" ").StartsWith("%")) {
            $Provider = $Provider[1];
        } else {
            $Provider = $Provider[0]
        }
    }
    $Provider = $Provider.Trim(' ')

    if ($Provider.StartsWith("%")) {
        $Provider = $Provider.Trim('%')
        #$Manufacter = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch "%$Provider2%=") -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
        $Manufacter = ($fileContent | Select-String "^$Provider\s*=") -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    }
    else {
        $Manufacter = ""
    }    

    $ClassGUID = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'ClassGUID=') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'

    if ($Manufacter.Length -eq 0) {
        $Manufacter = $Provider
    } elseif ($Manufacter.Length -gt 0 -And $Manufacter -is [system.array]) {
        if ($Manufacter.Length -gt 1 -And $Manufacter[0].Trim(" ").StartsWith("%")) {
            $Manufacter = $Manufacter[1];
        }
        else {
            $Manufacter = $Manufacter[0];
        }
    }
    $Manufacter = $Manufacter.Trim(' ').Trim('"')

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        Manufacturer = $Manufacter
        GUID = $ClassGUID
        Version = $dirverVer
    }
} | Format-Table -Property Name,Manufacturer,GUID,Version
```

Благодарю всех в поисках решения проблемы!

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" -Recurse -File -Filter '*.inf' | ForEach-Object {
    $fileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName

    $dirverVer = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'DriverVer=') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    $Provider = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Provider=') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    $Manufacter = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch "%$Provider%=") -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'
    $ClassGUID = ($fileContent | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'ClassGUID=') -replace '.*=(.*)','$1'

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        Manufacturer = if ($Manufacter) {$Manufacter} else {$Provider}
        GUID = $ClassGUID
        Version = $dirverVer
    }
} | Format-Table -Property Name,Manufacturer,GUID,Version
```

Comment: Все просто шикарно, есть одно "НО". Значения %MSFT% , %LSI% ,%MFGNAME%  и т.п. необходимо подставить (заменить) из .inf. Они описаны в нем. А для идеального решения, необходимо еще вывести список поддерживаемого оборудования, из этого драйвера. К примеру: Manufacter = "HP", Model = "HP Photosmart 2570" или "HP Color LaserJet 2820" (не важно, их может быть много) DriverVer = "6.1.7600.16385".

Comment: Как вариант дальше подстроку из процентов вытащить и взять её реальное занчение, в секции strings

Comment: Вот пример из разных INF:
1394.inf
`Provider=%MSFT%`
`[Manufacturer]
%Generic.Mfg%=Generic,NTamd64
%Legacy.Mfg%=Legacy,NTamd64
%Fujitsu.Mfg%=Fujitsu,NTamd64
%LSI.Mfg%=LSI,NTamd64
%NatSemi.Mfg%=NatSemi,NTamd64
%NEC.Mfg%=NEC,NTamd64
%Ricoh.Mfg%=Ricoh,NTamd64
%Sony.Mfg%=Sony,NTamd64
%TI.Mfg%=TI,NTamd64
%VIA.Mfg%=VIA,NTamd64

[Strings]
MSFT="Microsoft"`

adpu320.inf
`Provider=%ADP%`
`%ADP%=ADAPTEC,NTx86,NTamd64`

Как видите, единого стандарта нет. Нужно писать более сложный вариант для парсинга.
Секции Model вообще не нашёл ни в одном из двух INF, приведённых ниже.

Comment: Да уж. Что нет единого стандарта - знал. В этом то и изначальный затык был. Благодарю всех. вопрос скорее всего, можно считать решенным.